# CompoundJs, ExpressJs routes

Tags: node.js, express, compoundjs

I have NodeJs : 0.10.22 and compoundJs : 1.1.7-11

I have following Controller code:

```
module.exports = Rose;

function Rose(init){

}

Rose.prototype.index = function(c){
    c.send('Controller ROSE,  Function Index');
};

Rose.prototype.thorne = function thorne(c){
    c.send('Controller ROSE, Function Thorne');
};
```

I have defined following route in routes.js file :

```
exports.routes = function (map) {

    map.resources('rose', function(flower){
         //flower.get('thorne', '#thorne');
        flower.get('thorne');
    });
};
```

I have tried both lines in map.resources (one is currently remarked, but earlier it was used) in routes.js.

Following url works :

```
http://localhost:3000/rose
```

But following url doesn't work:

```
http://localhost:3000/rose/thorne
```

And it shows Following error:

```
Express
500 Error: Undefined action rose#show(/rose/thorne)
```

Can some one guide me what I am doing wrong and how it can be rectified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CompoundJS CRUD allows a list of a model to be viewed, and methods to manipulate individual data. When using `.resources`, several routes are generated. You can view them by running `compound routes` (or `compound r` for short). Some examples below using *roses* (plural):

```
roses GET        /roses.:format?          roses#index - Should return a list of roses
rose GET         /roses/:id.:format?      roses#show  - Displays a single rose
edit_rose GET    /roses/:id/edit.:format? roses#edit  - Brings up an edit form for a single rose
```

When mapping the route for a flower, compoundjs expects you to map a flower to one single rose. The route is defined as:

```
thorne_rose GET  /roses/:rose_id/thorne   roses#thorne
```

You have to pass in a rose id to access that particular rose's thorne. However, if you intend to only have one rose (no list of roses or anything), you can add the singleton option to the resource:

```
map.resources('rose', { singleton: true }, function(flower) {
    flower.get('thorne');
});
```

This will also eliminate the index route, instead use `Rose.prototype.show`. In a typical CRUD, the index lists all of the values for in the model. Since there is only one value, a list page is not needed.